# How do I keep the duplicate cells but get rid of cells that aren't duplicated?

Tags: sql, sql-server

So I have a column in a query which will show both duplicates and non-duplicates. I want to keep the rows with the duplicates but get rid of the rows without duplicate values.

It's a company ID number, and we need to see if this company comes up multiple times to show only the ones that do. Any help would be greatly appreciated because I have trawled the internet and everything I have tried won't work due to other sub queries (I didn't write the original query either which doesn't help!)

My data can be reproduced as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl 
(
    CaseID       VARCHAR(10),
    Appointed    VARCHAR(10),
    Closed       VARCHAR(10),
    CompanyID    INT
)

INSERT INTO tbl VALUES
('BESP01F', '27/07/2018' ,'26/09/2019' ,7801500 ),
('BESP01F', '27/07/2018' ,'26/09/2019' ,7801500 ),
('CITR01F', '03/02/2011' ,'18/03/2013' ,6209287 ),
('FOUR01F', '10/01/2019' ,'06/11/2019' ,6245409 ),
('MJBS01F', '29/11/2011' ,'28/01/2013' ,557544  ),
('MJBS01F', '29/11/2011' ,'28/01/2013' ,5575442 ),
('SLHG01F', '13/05/2011' ,'23/01/2013' ,4913396 ),
('SMIT03F', '31/07/2013' ,'19/08/2014' ,6890203 ),
('SMITH02F','31/07/2013', '11/08/2014', 6890329)
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  A text table is worth a thousand words.

Comment: You can select the Distinct values.. With distinct keyword. If you show me some example data I can write a query

Comment: Below is the table, essentially I don't want rows where the company ID isn't repeated

CaseID  Appointed Closed Company ID

BESP01F 27/07/2018 26/09/2019 7801500

BESP01F 27/07/2018 26/09/2019 7801500

CITR01F  03/02/2011 18/03/2013 6209287


FOUR01F 10/01/2019 06/11/2019 6245409

MJBS01F 29/11/2011 28/01/2013 5575442

MJBS01F 29/11/2011 28/01/2013 5575442

SLHG01F 13/05/2011 23/01/2013 4913396

SMIT03F  31/07/2013 19/08/2014 6890203

SMITH02F 31/07/2013 11/08/2014 6890329

Answer (score 0):

Try this. The subquery returns the company ID's with duplicate values and we use that as a filter on a `SELECT` from the original table

```
SELECT   *
FROM     tbl
WHERE    CompanyID IN (
                         SELECT    CompanyID
                         FROM      tbl
                         GROUP BY  CompanyID
                         HAVING    COUNT(*) > 1
                       )
```